# xcodebuild builds test target but cannot run xctest

Tags: xcodebuild, xctest, xpc

I run a command in terminal

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project awesome.xcodeproj -scheme "AwesomeTests" 
-configuration Production test -derivedDataPath ~/Documents/buildData
-sdk "OS X 10.9"
```

last lines of output looks like

```
error: failed to launch '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xctest'
-- error: Host::LaunchProcess (launch_info) => pid=0,
path='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver'
err = Problems with launching via XPC. XPC error : Connection interrupted (0x00000005)
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

Before outputing these lines I'm prompted with: "xcodebuild is trying to take control of a root process. Type your password to allow this"

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: Whoa, removing `sudo` part solved the mystery. Thank you, @trojanfoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @trojanfoe noted, the `sudo` was the cause of the error.

It seems like `~/Documents/buildData` folder was created with root permissions and couldn't be  accessed from `xtest`.